# I can't get logs to the console to work since ejecting from create-react-native-app?

Tags: react-native

When I run react-native log-ios in the the terminal the following warning repeats over and over again until i press ctrl+c (and nothing is logged to the console with console.log):

```
<Warning>: Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Dec 18 10:17:24 home com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.1336CFD7-B627-4A72-9DE9-5FAE927C1E82[3289] (com.apple.videosubscriptionsd) <Notice>: Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

I have also tried atom/nuclide, which I saw should log to the console automatically in another answer, but nothing I log shows up there either.

I'm not sure what other information I can provide.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you use console.log or is this for something that requires something more complicated?

Comment: @ShaneG I am just trying to use console.log, but it isn't working.

Comment: What console are you checking? On your simulator, press cmd+D and turn on remote debugging. That will bring up the correct console in your browser

Comment: @ShaneG that did it thanks.  Do you want to submit an answer?

Comment: I will now thanks. Glad to help

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-log-ios](https://github.com/Annihil/react-native-log-ios) npm pkg, it works out of the box without remote JS debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging in react-native you can do the following:

1. On your simulator, press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and turn on remote debugging. That will bring up the correct console in your browser
2. For a real device, shake it over and back in the app you are developing to bring up the developer options. Here you can also toggle this on and off